# Why can't I suddenly run NPX commands to my Visual Studio Code after encountering corrupted files?

Tags: react-native, visual-studio, expo, npx

This started when I accidentally shutdown my pc while visual studio code was open. Then when I tried to re-open my workspace(folder), it said that some folders in it were corrupted. Anyway, I am trying to create an app using ReactNative(Expo). Fortunately, I have compressed my file so I have the latest backup of the files. I did some coding after I tried to successfully extract the backup and use that as the new workingspace folder, but then an error popped up from Windows 10 that it wanted me to restart/shutdown the pc because of the corrupted files(?). I did shutdown it then it redirected me to the screen where it said "Fixing: Stage 1" After waiting for many minutes, I interrupted the process and restarted my pc. Then when I tried to re-open the visual studio code, I could no longer run NPX commands in my terminal which prevents me from running my App and install packages. I hope someone can help me with this as soon as possible because this is very important to me and to my classmates as we are working to create this application for our thesis/capstone that needs to be defended on October 24-25, 2023. Thank you!

I tried to reinstall VS Code but nothing happened. I don't know if it is not working or if it just takes too long to respond or take an action.